# Differentiate each term separately question

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Say I have this function:

$f(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n(2n+1)}$.  which its convergence interval is $-1\leq x\leq 1$.
If I differentiate it once I'd get:
$f'(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{x^{2n}}{2n}$
If I differentiate it once again I'd get:
$f''(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=1}x^{2n-1}$ = $\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{2n}$

What I don't understand is why the second derivative well defined? What would happen when $x=0$?
For the second derivative I would get division by zero

Comment: How do you get division by zero? Consider the limit, $\lim _{x\rightarrow 0} x\\
$. Can I rewrite it as $\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x^{2}}{x}\\$? Would it be logical? You have erroneously assumed so, and thus made a mistake.

Comment: @IshraaqParvez But you *can* rewrite $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} x$ as $ \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2}{x}$. There is nothing erroneous about it.

Comment: The only flaw I see with your reasoning is that you have abused a law of exponent, viz. $a^{m-n}=\frac{a^{m}}{a^n}$ if $a$ is a non-zero real number and $m$ and $n$ are integers. So, $x^{2n-1}≠\frac{x^{2n}}{x}$ unless $x$ is non-zero. See [laws of integer exponents here.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Integer_exponents)